PySide How to apply smoothing (antialiasing)?
There is a drawn arrow indicator. Everything works well, but deep irregularities (burrs) remain on the red sectors. How to remove it?
from PySide6.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QPolygon, QPaintEvent, QConicalGradient, QGradient, QBrush, QPainterPath
from PySide6.QtCore import Signal, QSize, QRect, QPoint, Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget
from typing import List, Tuple

class ArrowPointerIndicator(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,
                 chunks: List[Tuple[float, QColor]],
                 lineWidth: int = 5,
                 parent: QWidget = None) ->None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.__arrowColor: QColor = QColor(255, 0, 0)
        self.__gradient: QGradient = None
        self.setChunks(chunks)
        self.__arrow = QPolygon([
            QPoint(-2, -80),
            QPoint(0, -100),
            QPoint(2, -80),
            QPoint(2, 10),
            QPoint(-2, 10),
            QPoint(-2, -80)
        ])
        self.__minimum = -10.0
        self.__maximum = 10.0
        self.__lineWidth = lineWidth
        self.__value: float = 0.0
    def arrowColor(self) ->QColor:
        return self.__arrowColor  
    def setArrowColor(self, arrowColor: QColor) ->QColor:
        if self.__arrowColor == arrowColor:
            return
        self.__arrowColor = arrowColor
        self.update()
    def setChunks(self, chunks: List[Tuple[float, QColor]]) ->None:
        weightsSum: float = sum(item[0] for item in chunks)
        chunks = [(item[0] / weightsSum / 2, item[1]) for item in chunks]
        self.__gradient = QConicalGradient()
        passedWeight = 0.25
        for weight, color in chunks:
            self.__gradient.setColorAt(passedWeight, color)
            self.__gradient.setColorAt(passedWeight + weight - 0.0000000001, color)
            passedWeight += weight
        self.__gradient.setCenter(QPoint(0, 0))
        self.__gradient.setAngle(-90)
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event: QPaintEvent) ->None:
        super().paintEvent(event)
        drawSize = min(self.width() / 2, self.height())
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.translate(self.width() / 2, self.height())
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.RenderHint.Antialiasing)
        self.__drawColorArc(drawSize, painter)
        self.__drawArrowPointer(drawSize, painter)
    def __drawColorArc(self, drawSize: int, painter: QPainter) ->None:
        painter.save()
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addEllipse(-drawSize, -drawSize, 2 * drawSize, 2 * drawSize)
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(self.__gradient))
        drawingRect = QRect(-drawSize, -drawSize, 2 * drawSize, 2 * drawSize)
        painter.drawChord(drawingRect, 0, 180 * 16)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.RenderHint.Antialiasing)
        painter.restore()
    def __drawArrowPointer(self, drawSize: int, painter: QPainter) ->None:
        painter.save()
        painter.setBrush(self.__arrowColor)
        painter.scale(drawSize / 100.0, drawSize / 100.0)
        painter.drawConvexPolygon(self.__arrow)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.RenderHint.Antialiasing)
        painter.restore()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ArrowPointerIndicator(
            chunks=[
                (4, Qt.GlobalColor.white),
                (1, Qt.GlobalColor.red),
                (1, Qt.GlobalColor.white),
                (1, Qt.GlobalColor.red),
                (4, Qt.GlobalColor.white),
        ], lineWidth=1000000)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


I applied Antialiasing wherever there is Painter. Tried different combinations, but it looks like smoothing doesn't work here.
I had to place the code very tightly, sorry for the inconvenience.

The problem is caused by the narrow margins between stops: the raster painter "asks" the gradient about the color at a specific coordinate pixel, and the result is that it's either one or the other (it's actually a bit more complex than this, but that's the basic concept). If you don't actually need color transitions, you should opt for drawPie() for each color, and avoid gradients completely.

Note that you should avoid using the painter save() and restore() unless you really need them: it can make sense in __drawArrowPointer() (due to the scaling) but it seems quite unnecessary in __drawColorArc(). Painting should be as fast as possible, so any unnecessary changes in the painter should be avoided. Setting the render hint right before a restore() is also completely useless, since it has effect only from the moment it's set, but you're resetting the painter right after that. Besides, you already do that before calling the other functions, so it's unnecessary anyway.

Off-topic, unrelated, but still relevant. I see that you put a lot of attention to type hinting (which is fine, even though not important for a code example), but I suggest you to put the same level of attention (if not even more) to proper code styling too, as readability is equally important, at the very least. 1. separate all functions with blank lines; 2. more consistent indentation; 3. white spaces around operators (including ->); 4. stdlib imports should always come first. If you haven't yet, please check the official Style Guide for Python Code.
